# Send mock response based on request header content in soapui

Tags: groovy, mocking, soapui

I have two mock responses eg: A, B

I want to write condition for mock responses like

- if request header(ex:"myheader") value is "a" then send Mock response A
- if request header(ex:"myheader") value is "b" then send Mock response B

Comment: You can use script dispatcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is very much possible to mock using soapui.

Let us assume that when a rest service is invoked, it is possible to have different responses based on user's **request header** `Content-Type` value.

- xmlResponse
- jsonResponse
- faultResponse

So, add above three responses to the mock service. And user `SCRIPT` as dispatcher.

**Mock Service Script** as follows:

```
def responseType = mockRequest.request.getHeader('Content-Type')
if (!responseType) {
    return "faultResponse"
}
if ('application/json' == responseType.toLowerCase() || 'json' == responseType.toLowerCase()) {
    return "jsonResponse"   
} 
"xmlResponse"
```